# change only background color in html

Tags: html

Let us consider my text as

Jane Smith active

here is reference how i need, only active word should be in green and this( Jane Smith active ) should be in single line

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mgNc.png)

what i have tried is

```
Jane Smith <p style="background-color:green;"> Active</p>
```

Here is image how i am getting

[reference for how i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf0CG.png)

Answer (score 1):

The p tag is a block element. You have now two opportunities to change the behavoir.

1. Set the p display to inline; `Jane Smith <p style="background-color:green; dipslay: inline;"> Active</p>`
2. use instead p a span tag. `Jane Smith <span style="background-color:green;"> Active</span>`

Answer (score 0):

You could change the width of that

element. Or even better just make an other

element for "Active"

Answer (score 0):

use `<span>` instead of `<p>`

[p](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) stands for paragraph and always starts on a new line

Comment: A `<div>` is also a block level element and cause the same issue he's having.

Comment: you're right I'm editing this answer, ty

Answer (score 0):

Use `<span>` tag not `<p>` tag

```
Jane Smith <span style="background-color:green;"> Active</span>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Jane Smith  Active

If you're trying to achieve it all in one line of HTML:

```html
<p>Jane Smith <span style="background-color: blue">Active</span></p>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The **p** element is a block level element so it will always start on the next line, you should use a **span** which is an inline element so it will keep the text on the same line.

Even better try using the **mark** tag that gives text a highlight and you can change the color using `"background-color:lime"` in the same way you normally would (default is yellow)

```
<p>Jane Smith is <span style="background-color:lime">Active</span> </p>
```

Or

```
<p>Jane Smith is <mark style="background-color:lime">Active</mark> </p>
```